# Redirect Loop with Azure CDN

Tags: azure, routes, nginx-config, azure-cdn, microsoft-cdn

I have domains `example.com` & `www.example.com`

The `www.` subdomain is attached to an *Azure CDN*, using *Microsoft CDN Classic*.
I tried to map the `non www.` to the CDN with the following *NGINX* config:

```
server 
{
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The intent here is to redirect everything from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

But it results in a site-wide `301 "Too many redirects"`.
However, when i turn off the CDN (e.g. disassociate the `www.` domain), that config works just fine.

I tried to add a custom non-shared SSL certificate to `example.com` but that didnt fix it.

How can i make this work with the CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to fix this at its root via *NGINX* config or the *Azure* interface but managed with a workaround:

I unregistered the `non www.` domain from *Azure* and pointed it to an alternate webspace which then redirects to the `www.` domain of the CDN.
This way `www.` and `non www.` are working properly with the CDN. The workaround is agreeable ugly but not noticeable to a user.